# How to identify Sqoop failures and handle them?

Tags: sql-server, shell, validation, hive, sqoop

I am exporting the data from hive table to SQLServer table using sqoop, but at times all the records do not get exported.

I'm not sure how to identify this failure without manual intervention. I have a plan to solve this issue by writing a shell script that -

1) Stores the count of hive table in a variable.
2) Stores the count of SQL Server table in another variable.
3) Compares the value of the two variables,

```
    if var1 != var 2 
    { 
       Delete the rows in SQL Server Server;
        Rerun my sqoop script
    }
    else
       exit;
```

Questions: 
With my current approach,
How to store the count of rows of a hive table in a variable in a shell script?
How to store the count of rows of a table in SQL-Server-Management studio in a shell script?

Comment: Is it that sqoop command fails and u want to check its status or sqoop command runs fine but still doesnt import entire dataset?

Comment: Sqoop command runs fine but at time doesn't export all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop provides an *out of the box* validation tool to ensure the correctness of import/export performed. You can do this using following flag:

```
--validate
```

Please refer https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#validation which details out all 3 validation interfaces.

As per which,

> Validator - Drives the validation logic by delegating the decision to ValidationThreshold and delegating failure handling to ValidationFailureHandler. The default implementation is RowCountValidator which validates the row counts from source and the target.

You can further take actions on the validation output by implementing your own Validator as below:

> The validation framework is extensible and pluggable. It comes with default implementations but the interfaces can be extended to allow custom implementations by passing them as part of the command line arguments as described below.

[image]

Comment: I used the --validate statement but it gives me an error.               ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Error validating row counts
Which brings me to a question if the row counts on both the tables do not match, will it rerun the sqoop statement?                                            If yes then will I have duplicate values in my SQl server table?

Comment: Not sure about the `error` during validating the row count, posting error trace would help. Now, if the row counts on both the tables do not match, as the document says you can provide `validation-failurehandler` where you need to implement `org.apache.sqoop.validation.ValidationFailureHandler` and here you can decide whether to rerun or not.

Comment: How do I implement what needs to be done in ValidationFailureHandler?

Comment: Those are the standard interfaces. You can find those on mentioned sqoop documentation. You can implement what needs to be done after failure in this handler in java.

Comment: The reason I get an error validating the count is because I am doing an export of daily records to SQL-Server. But SQL Server has multiple days worth of rows while Hive table just one, which makes it never to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your are trying to do the reconciliation after exporting the data from hive to sqlserver. To get the counts from sqlserver you can write java/scala jdbc program.

Below are the pseudo code

```
hiveCount = `hive -e "select count(*) from foo_table"`
sqlServerCount= java/scala jdbcCount.jar
```